# Retag doctrine2 to doctrine-orm

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Yesterday we [have started the process of renaming](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/7552) PHP's `doctrine/doctrine2` library to `doctrine/orm`. On behalf of the Doctrine team I would like to ask for a retag of the [doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine2) tag to [doctrine-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine-orm).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I have made the following renames (and added synonyms from the old to the new)

- [doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine2) to [doctrine-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine-orm)
- [doctrine2-postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine2-postgres) to [doctrine-orm-postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine-orm-postgres)
- [doctrine2-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine2-filters) to [doctrine-orm-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine-orm-filters).

(Those last two may need re-evaluating, as there were a dozen or so questions on the former, and only two on the latter, but I figured I'd rename anyway for consistency).